# Церковнославянская раскладка в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, кодировка, клавиатура, локаль

Необходимо набирать текст на церковнославянском языке. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Церковно-славянский в Linux](http://sovety.blogspot.com/2009/02/church-slavonic-in-linux.html)
- [Как установить церковнославянские шрифты](http://wiki.orthodic.org/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D1%8B)
- [Методы реализации церковно-славянского письма в компьютерных системах](http://www.irmologion.ru/developer/fontdev.html)
- [Для разработчиков](http://wiki.orthodic.org/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)
- [Церковнославянский язык в Линуксе](http://www.flickr.com/photos/massalim/3271025343/)